# OS X: Strange NSTableView behaviour, InterfaceBuilder

Tags: macos, interface-builder, nstableview

Using InterfaceBuilder, I created a window and placed a table within it. When the table is populated with data, it fits horizontally and needs vertical scrolling. But when I scroll the table, the vertical scroller is not displayed, and a bit of a horizontal scroller is displayed in the bottom right corner of the table view. That horizontal scroller moves (horizontally) when I scroll the table vertically, and the table scrolls very-very fast indeed.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

I tried removing the table and creating it anew, but this happens every time. Tried googling it as well, but in vain.

Has anyone faced this problem and found a way out?

**UPD**: I am using Xcode 5

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue -- looks like this came with Xcode 5 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the xib file in your favorite text editor and look for the following entry associated with the misbehaving tableview:

```
<scroller key="verticalScroller" hidden="YES" verticalHuggingPriority="750" id="xNY-Po-yr0">
  <rect key="frame" x="484" y="17" width="16" height="0.0"/>
  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
</scroller>
```

... the `height` is set to `0.0`, but that doesn't seem right. Set it to something like `100` - in my testing this resolves the issue.

**Edit:**
It seems that the problem can also be resolved by selecting the containing Scroll View, un-checking "Automatically Hide Scroller", then re-enabling it. This effectively re-sets the "0.0" height to whatever it should be.

Comment: it may bear mentioning that the height cannot be set via interface builder -- editing is disabled for the scroller dimensions.

Comment: Fixes the problem for me